# Include jQuery dependent code with Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

I am evaluating to use GTM with our product website. We have javascript code which uses jQuery which we need to inject in page using GTM.

The GTM code is included right after body tag is defined. How can I include jQuery code with GTM which waits for jQuery to be available?

Will window.load work?

Comment: Can't you include jQuery in the head?

Comment: It is already included in the page after the GTM tag. I dont have access to change that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your jQuery dependent tags to fire on "DOM Ready" (or "window loaded") in GTM (e.g. via the dropdown in the pageview trigger configuration). This will defer tag execution until, well, the DOM has rendered and by then the script tag that includes jQuery is processed (and you won't need `$( document ).ready()` in your  jQuery scripts since this is more or less the same as GTM's DOM Ready).